# ArcGIS Server Manager keeps getting COM errors

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I am using ArcGIS Server 10 on IIS6.  While publishing out mapping services/restarting services/deleting services, I keep getting various COM errors like the one below..after viewing the Event log it looks like the ServiceWizard.aspx file is generally the root cause.

However, usually if I wait thirty minutes or go to the restroom or other seemingly non-related activity and then try again it that I was trying to do will work.

The errors are a little to scattered to describe fully.  The question is..Is there something I may be doing wrong or should I restart the SOM every few days or another option?  FYI, there are a lot of mapping services on this instance.  Thanks.

"An error has occured on the server. For details please check the Event (Application) log on the web server.
Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."